# Actor error while running the server

Tags: actor-platform

I am running Actor in Ubuntu 14. It's installed using automatic install script.
After [installing actor.im](https://actor.readme.io/docs/server-install) and running the server, I ran the webApp, in console it says:

```
AuthKeyActor: Sending RequestStartAuth
app.js:102 AuthKeyActor: Received ResponseStartAuth
app.js:102 AuthKeyActor: Sending RequestGetServerKey
app.js:102 AuthKeyActor: Crashing connection
app.js:102 AuthKeyActor: onConnectionDie
app.js:102 AuthKeyActor: Too old: ignoring
```

and in server log, it says:

```
18:18:29.665UTC DEBUG akka.io.TcpListener akka.tcp://actor-server@[MY.IP]:2552/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/1 New connection accepted
18:18:29.670UTC DEBUG im.actor.server.frontend.WsFrontend$ WsFrontend$(akka://actor-server) New HTTP Connection /[CLIENT.IP]:1283
18:18:31.905UTC DEBUG akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(actor-server) Closing connection conn-ws-3
```

Can you please let me know what is wrong there?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate encryption keys using actor-cli:

```
actor-cli key -c -o /etc/actor/key1
```